# Problems with camera view and lighting (openGL & GLUT)

Tags: opengl, glut, light, perspectivecamera

[image]

I am trying to implement the bottom subwindow with three torus, but failed to display anything on the subwindow..

main function for subwindow:

```
instrument_window = glutCreateSubWindow(main_window, GAP, view_height + 3*GAP, 2*(view_width+GAP), INSTRUMENT_HEIGHT);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
//lighting
const GLfloat light_ambient[] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_diffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat light_position[] = { 600, 1200, 1200, 0.0f };

const GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
const GLfloat high_shininess[] = { 100.0f };

//glClearColor(0.33,0.33,0.33,0.33);
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glCullFace(GL_BACK);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, light_specular);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, high_shininess);
//end of lighting

glutMainLoop();
```

for display function:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

float width = 2*(GAP+view_width);
float height = INSTRUMENT_HEIGHT;
const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;

//glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glFrustum(width/4.0, width*3.0/4.0, height*3.0/4.0, height/4.0, 2.0, 100.0);
//gluPerspective (160.0, 2*view_width/INSTRUMENT_HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000.0);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity() ;
/*
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
// Reset transformations
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective (160.0, 2*view_width/INSTRUMENT_HEIGHT, 0.1, 1000.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

// Draw first
draw (view_width+GAP-400, INSTRUMENT_HEIGHT/2);

// Draw second
draw (view_width+GAP-150, INSTRUMENT_HEIGHT/2);

// Draw third
draw (view_width+GAP+100, INSTRUMENT_HEIGHT/2);
```

for draw function:

```
void draw(double cx,double cf)
glColor3f(0.34f,0.34f,0.34f);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslated(0.0, cx, cy);
glRotated(-10, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glutSolidTorus(OUTER_DIAL_RADIUS, OUTER_DIAL_RADIUS+30, 100, 200);
glPopMatrix();
end
```

really frustrating since it just display nothing and don't know how to debug. Any hints are highly appreciate!!!!

Comment: In future please don't delete questions after they have been answered. This is a Q&A community for everyone currently, and importantly anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, its difficult to answer this question from the code example supplied. Half of the 'displayFunction' is commented out from the `/*` so nothing below it will get called. Even then its difficult to deduce the problem since there is little code relating to multiple viewports here. Since you are using fixed pipeline GL look at NeHe which has a good tutorial on employing multiple viewports.

http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/multiple_viewports/20002/

Debugging is the single most important tool a developer has in their arsenal to resolve problems. It would be wise to learn how to do this as it would certainly save you time in the long run and you will find the answers to most (if not all) of your coding problems!

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem here is actually the parameter of perspective. I am sorry for the previous delete. I was thinking it might be a duplicate question and I didn't know much about the rules here. I will try to migrate the whole program to the new version of openGL . Thanks for the link you provide.